# Android chronometer ticks once and stops

Tags: android, timer, chronometer

I need to hide a TextView after 10 seconds. I thought I could implement a Chronometer and when elapsed time is bigger than 10000 millis I hide the TextView. My problem is that the chronometer only ticks once and then stops. Any idea what I've missed ?

```
Activity ctx = this;
...

private void ShowText(String message)
    {
        txtProceed.setText(message);
        txtProceed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        chronoHideText = new Chronometer(ctx);
        chronoHideText.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener()
        {
               public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {

                  long elapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronoHideText.getBase();
                  Log.i("Chrono",String.valueOf(elapsed));
                   if (elapsedTime>10000)
                   {
                       txtProceed.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                       chronoHideText.stop();
                   }
               }
        }
        );

        chronoHideText.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chronoHideText.start();

    }
```

Thank you Janusz for  your help. The solution that works great now is:

```
Handler splashHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    switch (msg.what) {
                    case 0:
                            //remove SplashScreen from view
                            txtProceed.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            break;
                    }
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
    };

    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = 0;
    splashHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 10000);
```

Comment: Are you really making your user sit through a *10 second* splash screen?  Please don't do that.

Comment: It's not a splash screen, it a info message while to user keeps using the app. It doesn't bother him, it's just a small text on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [handler](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageDelayed%28android.os.Message,%20long%29) that sends a delayed message. 
The method sendMessageDelayed gives you the ability to specify a time and after that time elapsed you will get a message. If you only need to do one thing after the elapsed time you can just hide the view in your [handleMessage](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Handler.html#handleMessage%28android.os.Message%29) method.

This way you don't need to measure the time yourself and do computation work every second or millisecond. Your app won't take any cpu time until the message is delivered by the Android OS.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ButtonVisibility extends Activity {

Button mButton;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_button);

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    new MyTask().execute(null);
}

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("MyTask", "InterruptedException", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
  }
```

}